# Путаница в promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Возникло некое непонимание в промисах. 
Основная функция `a()` и функция `b()`, в которой происходит обращение к базе. После выполнения функции `b()`, результат нужно передать в `a()` для дальнейшей обработки. Но как я понимаю, `resolve( b(user) )` вызывается раньше, чем отработает `b()`. 
Как можно решить проблему?

```
function a(){

    var info = {email: 'email@email.ru'},
        user = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          resolve( b(user) );
        });

    user.then(function(result) {

     res.send( result );
    });
}

function b(params){

    model.user.findAll({

        where:{ email: params['email'] }

    }).then(function(user){

        return(user);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция `b` уже может возвращать Promise, если добавите return, поэтому нет нужды создавать его в функции `a`

```
function a(){

    var info = {email: 'email@email.ru'},
        user = b(info);

    user.then(function(result) {
        res.send( result );
    });
}

function b(params){

    return model.user.findAll({

        where:{ email: params['email'] }

    }).then(function(user){

        return(user);
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.